# Bigcommerce Cross-origin Image Issue

Tags: javascript, bigcommerce

I'm using the background-check.js to change headings color according to the background images. Though I'm getting some CORS issues with the images served by Bigcommerce CDN.

I managed to surpass those issues on the homepage carousel because They actually send the "Access-Control-Allow-Origin:*" header along with those images.

But when I went on to apply everything I've done to the category page, the image added there wasn't served with that same header.

The use of the CDN obviously brings good flexibility but shouldn't take possibilities off of developers using images to their need. Not even online it will work since they don't have the CDN on the same domain...

For me this is obviously an error since some have and some don't.

Is there any way to surpass this on the Bigcommerce end? And is there any thing that can be done to the plugin? Hack it a bit?

Thanks a lot!

**Edit:**
As asked for:

```
import $ from 'jquery';
import Radio from 'radio/radio';
import BackgroundCheck from '../../vendor/background-check-master/background-check.js';

export default function () {
    const $textsOverImages = $('.change-color');
    const $imageBackgrounds = $('.image_background');

    if ($textsOverImages.length && $imageBackgrounds.length) {
        if (BackgroundCheck) {
            BackgroundCheck.init({
                targets: '.change-color',
                images: '.image_background',
                minComplexity: 30,
                threshold: 30,
            });
        }

        Radio('fullpage/afterLoad').subscribe( BackgroundCheck.refresh );
    }
}
```

and on the image to overstep the cross-origin image problem on the homepage images I'm doing: 
`<img crossorigin class="image_img image_background" src="{{image}}" alt="{{alt_text}}"/>`

Comment: Are you trying to use these images on a BigCommerce store or somewhere else? And can you share the code you are using?

Comment: I'm trying to use those within a BigCommerce store. I didn't put in any code because I thought it wasn't worth sharing in this case. I'm just initiating the backgroundCheck.js plugin if there are background images present.